# Is there a way how to get current song title playing in a shoutcast stream using a third party api when the current song information is not provided?

Tags: javascript, shoutcast

I have a stream for a live radio but the shoutcast stream is not providing the current song information. So i was thinking if there is any third party api where i can can pass music played to the api and it returns the song information.

Comment: https://developer.gracenote.com/ could work. Shazam and Soundhound don't appear to have one.

Comment: It looks like it will need me to be provide the artist, album title or track title. From the live stream am using there is none of those and i was just thinking maybe if i can pass the live stream to the api and it can return the song title.

Comment: I meant this: https://developer.gracenote.com/gnsdk "MusicID recognition for identifying CDs, digital music files, and streaming audio."

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/free-music-recognition-api This could help too